# Instafeed.js with load more option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using instafeed.js to display instagram photos. What would be the easiest way to add a function to show more instagram images after the first set of pictures have loaded with load more button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **[v1.3.0](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/releases/tag/v1.3.0)**, there is a `.next()` function you can use to load more results:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  // ...
});

// call feed.next() on button click
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
  feed.next();
});

// run the feed
feed.run();
```